# Unable to find the embedded reports in Jenkins, although I provided the embed BrowserStackReport option

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

Unable to find the embedded reports in Jenkins, although I provided the embed BrowserStackReport option. The BrowserStack video is present when I login to the browserstack account

Answer (score 0):

Browserstack Jenkins reporting feature currently only works with the below:
​
1) Java - TestNg and JUnit
2) Node JS - Webdriver IO and Protractor

Comment: It is a Maven Project using Java and TestNG framework. The jenkins job runs on browserstack . but the report generated isnt embedded in the result. that is the issue.